# how to use hive snapshot on CDP?

Tags: hive, hdfs, cloudera, snapshot

We want to use HDFS Snapshot to protect data from humain error.
But i want to know how we can restore snapshot of hive table.
I know that we will need to recreate schemas/tables again but how we can use it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The HDFS directory will be having a .snapshot directory inside your snapshottable directory.
Copy the data inside the /.snapshot/ directory to any new location or replace it with the current location and you should be sorted.